# Como comunicar una sesión creada en laravel 5.1 con Codeigniter 3.0

Tags: laravel, codeigniter-3, session

Tenemos una aplicación creada en laravel 5.1, pero necesitamos por cuestiones de tiempo utilizar grocery Crud para Codeigniter 3 para generar las tablas maestras.

Necesitamos utilizar el mismo login con los dos Frameworks.